# Req.file Is showing Undefined in Nodejs Express - (multer and Without Multer both)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, pug, multer

Getting a Strange Error I have tried Everything but My code Doest not pick up Req.file..
I AM new to Nodejs And Express, AND i was try to upload an image using multer. 
Req.file is showing UNDEFINED and Image is not uploading
This is my source code with using PUG(template engine)
**Bumper.pug**

```html
   

 extends base.pug

    block style
        style
            include ../static/productUpload.css
    block scripts
        script(src="../static/categorienav.js")
        //- script(src="../static/productid.js")
        

    block content
        p.heading
            | Upload BUMPER
            .UploadPage
                .Uploadinfo
                    p#PID BUMPER
                form.uploadform(action=`/BumperUpload` , method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data")
                    input.catsclass(type="file",name="file" accept="image/*" required)
                    input.catsclass(type="text",name="Link",placeholder="paste Link here" required)
                    input.catsclass(type="submit")
                    |   #{Change}
```

Bumper.js

```js
var express = require('express'); 
var myrouter= express.Router(); 
var bodyparser = require('body-parser'); 
var fs = require('fs'); 
var multer = require('multer'); 
// Initialize the express object 
var app = express();      
  
// Use body-parser to parse incoming data 
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : true}))      
app.set('view engine', 'pug') // Set the template engine as pug
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/views', __dirname + '/views2']); // Set the views directory


myrouter.get('/BumperUpload',(req,res)=>{

res.render('Bumper.pug');

  })
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        console.log(file);
        callback(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
myrouter.post('/BumperUpload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
  if (req.file) {
    console.log('Uploading File');
    var profileImageOriginlName=req.file.originalname;
    var profileImageName=req.file.name;
    var profileImageMime=req.file.mimetype;
    var profileImagePath=req.file.path;
    var profileImageExt=req.file.extension;
    var profileImageSize=req.file.size;
}
else
{
    var profileImageName='noimage.png';
}

console.log(profileImageName);
res.send("done")


});
module.exports = myrouter;
```

Index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const port = 80;
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
// var http = require('http');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// var mail = require("./static/mail.js")
//////mongojson = require("./mongodb.js")
var domain = require("domain").create();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var HOME = require('./models/HOME/HOME.js')
var Bumper = require('./models/HOME/Bumper.js');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use('/static', express.static('static')) // For serving static files
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(fileUpload());

// PUG SPECIFIC STUFF
app.set('view engine', 'pug') // Set the template engine as pug
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/views', __dirname + '/views2']); // Set the views directory
app.use('/', Bumper);
// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port, () => {
    // //console.log(res);
    //console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "rk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "param.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "domain": "0.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "filesystem": "^1.0.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "localStorage": "^1.0.4",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.14",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon param.js"
  },
  "author": "RISHABH GARG",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```
Result:
Database Connected <br>
undefined // req.file is showing undefined<br>
noimage.png //image is not upload<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the solution I Uninstall the Express-FileUpload and now it works